# Ubuntu 16.04 apt-get: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned error code (1)

Tags: apt, grub2, dependencies, udev

```
...
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
udev
grub-common
grub2-common
grub-pc-bin
grub-pc
lightdm
cups-browsed
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-video-intel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried "apt-get --fix-broken install XXXXX" but it didn't work. "dpkg-reconfigure --force XXXXX" also didn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install xorg-video-abi-20`.

Comment: I tried but the same error code is coming again... :(

Comment: an you have right i used the dpkg-reconfigure command as well

Comment: the error is some dependecies problem among the software packages mentioned, and an infinite loop is solved by stopping the configuratioan without unconfiguring the mentioned packages

Comment: Try running `sudo rm /var/crash/*` then running your `sudo apt-get -f install` again.

Comment: It would also be great if you could post the entire output of your apt-get command: I feel like there's a lot of missing information.

Comment: more than 34 thousand caracter is the error message I am not able to post it

Comment: @PolloLaszlo, you can post complete output on http://pastebin.com/ and add link in your question

Comment: i tried running your command but the error is the same after deleting the crash files

Comment: i am here now and not on the initial message

Comment: the system do not allow to modify the original starting message

Comment: here is the psatebin link:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/23eMCrBQ

Comment: i use Hungarian language

Comment: as I see this error is too misterious even for the experts... :(